# Exchange crypto key through sockets

Tags: java, sockets, encryption, cryptography

What i am making is a chat program that encrypts/decrypts messages send. So far i've established the basic all-to-all communication with clients and have put a server-to-client simple encryption with AES, basically i have given them the same key. Now i want to establish a key exchange algorithm that will allow every client to have its own key. I have read multiple algorithms, at first i wanted to establish a Diffie-Hellman but i found some RSA examples that made more sence. This is what i have:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, 
InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException  {

KeyGenerator keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
keyGenerator.init(128);
Key aesKey = keyGenerator.generateKey();



KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
keyPairGenerator.initialize(1024);
KeyPair keyPair = keyPairGenerator.genKeyPair();

Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");

byte[] aesKeyBytes = aesKey.getEncoded();
System.out.println("1. aesKeyBytes= "+ bytesToHex(aesKeyBytes));

cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keyPair.getPublic());
byte[] cipherText = cipher.doFinal(aesKeyBytes);
System.out.println("2. cipherText= "+bytesToHex(cipherText));

cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keyPair.getPrivate());
byte[] decryptedKeyBytes = cipher.doFinal(cipherText);
System.out.println("3. decryptedKeyBytes= "+bytesToHex(decryptedKeyBytes));


//use symmetric with the decrypted key
SecretKey newAesKey = new SecretKeySpec(decryptedKeyBytes, "AES");
```

Basically from the point this code ends i just use the SecretKey to initialize my AES cipher and go on from there. Now my question is how to distribute the keys from the RSA through sockets without losing bytes or whatever so that all clients can have unique keypairs with the server. Also is there a way to not use a keygenerator and give my own keys like Strings, since i plan on using setters so that the user can change his/her key on whish, otherwise what's the point in using keyexchange if all the clients end up having the same keys in the first place? And one last thing purely on curiosity, is it possible to modify this RSA to DH, and how are they different code-wise?
Lastly the "bytesToHex" method is as follows and was provided to me by my teacher and after tested it works fine so there are no problems there:

```
public static String bytesToHex(byte[] data)
{

    if (data==null)
        return null;
    else
    {
        int len = data.length;

        String str = "";

        for (int i=0; i<len; i++)
        {
            if ((data[i]&0xFF)<16){
                str = str + "0" + java.lang.Integer.toHexString(data[i]&0xFF);
                            }
                            else{
                str = str + java.lang.Integer.toHexString(data[i]&0xFF);
                            }
        }

        return str.toUpperCase();
    }
}
```

I know there might be answers like "look at this" and "this is a good example", but trust me i've looked at all of them i just got more confused. Just to be clear i don't want to use Files to store my keys or anything like that, i want simply the client and server to send each other their public keys so that along with their private key to create a secretKey, i know that this is basically DH but honestly i am so fed up right now that i'll take what i can get so anything you have to say is much appreciated.

Comment: How does the client know the public key it received is really from the server? That is, a man-in-the-middle attacker could send his own keys instead and proceed to decrypt all communication. To prevent this you need some sort of authentication. More on the subject in [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/09/27/keep-it-secret-keep-it-safe.aspx). Basically, it's simply easier and safer to make use of an existing protocol like [TLS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security) than to roll your own.

Comment: Well you that's what i am supposed to present. This is basically my Degree project so i can't just use a ready-to-go protocol, i actually have to make my own. Of course i don't have to create my own libraries but i can't just go like SSLSocket = new SSLSocket and say "i'm done".
Also the server client use simple input/output streams not anything special. What i want to do is something where the server has agreed a different key for each client and simple decrypts the message it receives and encrypts it again using each key for each client.

Comment: Of course if someone gains access to the server he could simply get the data on hand or as you said give his own key. I don't know if i have covered this so far but i intend to store those keys encrypted in database with something like SHA1 or MD5 so there is now way to decrypt them the only visible one would be the public key which is destributed for the algorithms to work, but that is for later and also my project isn't about protection from access attacks but about data encryption mostly so noone can get them during transfer.

Comment: If this is for a degree, please read a bit more into cryptography. You cannot say things like "encrypted in a database with something like SHA1 or MD5" and pass any kind of exam. Please split the protocol and the programming part; first think out a good protocol, make sure that is reviewed, then proceed with the programming.

Comment: Well i think that we are going off topic here, as i said i will look into the database later since it's for extra grade. My main program is the chat with the encrypted data and that is where i am having a problem.